# Most elegant way to deal with singles/plurals?

Tags: code-readability

Say you're making a blog software, and want to show the number of comments an entry got. You might do it this way:

```
[Entry title]
[Content........]
[ <?php print($numComments;) ?> Comments]
```

Which might result in:

```
[Entry title]
[Content........]
5 Comments
```

But if an entry had only 1 comment, I want the line to say 'Comment' rather than 'Comments'. And in-line `if/else`s are ugly and repetitive.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: +1 For your username, because it told me to. That is a clever and I'd be interested in knowing how many upvotes you got for that alone. :)

Comment: I'm half-tempted to downvote just to counteract the effects of people who upvote

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please use the [`ngettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php) function for things like this. It
allows you to deal correctly with plurals in English and other
languages, once and for all. You use it like this:

```
printf(ngettext("%d Comment", "%d Comments", $numComments), $numComments);
```

The `ngettext` function will return the first format string (`"%d
Comment"`) if there is just a single comment and the second format
string (`"%d Comments"`) if there are more. The `printf` function will
then put the number into the string.

This might seem like a lot of work, but it is very powerful: it works
with languages that have **more than one plural form(!)** -- they
actually exist. The PHP manual gives an example for the word "window"
which becomes "1 okno", "2 okna" and "*5 oken*" in some exotic
language I don't recognize...

If you are consequent about using `ngettext`, then your future users
from far-away countries will be very grateful to you :-)

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments, there is a single function to
  do the above:

```
function pluralize($num, $singleWord, $pluralWord) {
    return printf(ngettext($singleWord, $pluralWord, $num), $num);
}
```

By default, `xgettext` wont recognize this new function, but you can
add it with the `--keyword` flag. Given a file `test.php` with

```
echo ngettext("foo", "foos", 1);
echo pluralize(2, "bar", "bars");
```

you can extract the strings with

```
xgettext --keyword=pluralize:2,3 test.php
```

The resulting `messages.po` file has entries like these:

```
#: test.php:7
msgid "foo"
msgid_plural "foos"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""

#: test.php:8
msgid "bar"
msgid_plural "bars"
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""
```

The translator will fill in each plural form and with a correctly
formed "Plural-Forms" line in the message catalog header, you will be
able to support all languages.

Comment: it would be repetitive to use this with a printf all the time, but perhaps a wrapper function can be written which does the printf and the %d. Perhaps you could write the body of this function and update your answer? `function pluralize($num,$singleWord,$pluralWord='')`

Comment: @Click Upvote: good idea. I made the function with three mandatory arguments -- the plural string is necessary so that xgettext can recognize the function call and treat it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Why not take the time to humanize things even more....

```
switch ($numComments)
{
    case 0:
        echo "Be the first to write a comment";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "Just one comment so far";
        break;
    default:
        echo "There are $numComments comments";

}
```

Comment: @fishlips: except when a language has three or more plural forms. As explained below, the ngettext function is the more general solution. It allows a translator to include all his plural forms in the ".po" file and the right one will be selected at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that takes a number and a word, and returns a string containing both. It will append an "s" (or consult a dictionary that you build) when the number is bigger than 1.

Comment: I would make the function add the s if the number is not 1, so that 0 gets the plural form as well.

Comment: What would you call such a function?

Comment: Pluralize seems like the most fitting name.

Comment: +1 This is the proper way, but can get complicated when you have to deal with the different variations in the English language. (ie. Activity you'd need to make Activities instead of Activity). Having a dictionary that you build is proper, but can be a pain to keep up with.

Comment: May be the 3rd argument passed to this function can be the plural word? E.g, if you did: `pluralize($num,'Comment');` it would return 'Comments', but if you did: `pluralize(($num,'Activity','Activities');` then it returns Activities rather than Activitys

Comment: @Click Upvote: you have just invented something similar to the ngettext function, please see my answer below :-)

Comment: This can (and will) get complicated when the software needs to be localized, as some languages handle plural/singular differently from English.

Comment: Well some languages are even more complicated. Singular, dual and plural each of them related to masculinity and repeated again with numbers like 101, 102, 10X... 201... So. Not all languages are as easy as English when it comes to this problem.

Comment: I would also say that not all languages are as *difficult* as English when it comes to this problem :)

Answer (score 3):

It surprises me that nobody suggested that yet, but what I usually do is to use the conditional operator:

```
string commentWord = numComments != 1 ? "Comments" : "Comment";
```

Note: the string should of course not be hard coded like this at all, but rather loaded from some resource repository, where it is stored with a formatting placeholder for the number, so that you can handle languages where the number should appear last (or in the middle):

```
// should load "{0} Comments" or "{0} Comment" if we run in an English locale
string comments = string.Format(
        numComments != 1 ? GetResource("Comments") : GetResource("Comment"),
        numComments);
```

Comment: This is not the right way to do internationalization.  Language other than English have their own rules for plural forms; e.g. Lithuanian has three different forms: "1 komentaras", "2 komentarai", "10 komentarų".

The GNU gettext framework popular in C programs has a solution for this (the ngettext function).  I'm not familiar with Java/C#/PHP so I cannot say what is the canonical correct solution there.

Comment: @Marius: thanks for that information. I was not aware of those Lithuanian rules. I have done a bit of international software (event made a translation software of UI texts for a large client) but have never come across such demands. Very interesting! I will not dive into it in detail here though, I just wanted to introduce the concept of picking up the texts from a resource repository, rather than just hard coding them.

Comment: @Fredrik: I was also surpriced the first time I heard of languages with more than two plural forms... I'm Danish and used to just two forms :-) Luckily, the ngettext function can deal with it, please see my answer somewhere else on this page.

Comment: Plenty of languages have more than two plural forms; for example, IIRC, all Slavic languages do (Russian certainly does).

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant, but the easiest it to output "Comment(s)".

```
[Entry title]
[Content........]
1 Comment(s)
```

Comment: As you note, this not very elegant... When I see such output, I always wonder why the computer didn't spend the extra millisecond to figure out if the "s" should be there or not :-)

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++, you can do the following. You may be able to do something similar in PHP.

```
printf("%d %s\n", numComments, numComments == 1 ? "Comment" : "Comments");
```

The following also works, but you may run into issues with `\b` (backspace) being handled incorrectly in different implementations.

```
printf("%d Comment%s\n", numComments, numComments == 1 ? " \b" : "s");
```

Using `\0` (null character) to print nothing, instead, printed a space in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Rails inflector module](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html). This provides a nice, centralized and configurable solution to this problem.